# Haskell get all the numbers whose sum is X

Tags: haskell, subset-sum

I need to create a function in haskell which receives a number and returns a list of lists, where the list has all combination of the numbers whose sum is the number received.

is dificult to explain so this is the example:

```
sum1 4 = [ [4], [3,1], [2,2], [1,3], [1,1,2], [1,2,1] , [2,1,1] ]

sum1 3 = [ [3], [2,1], [1,2], [1,1,1]
```

I need to do this with recursion and with comprehension list

**EDIT**

this is my code:

```
sum1 n = sum3 (sum2 1 (n-1) n)
sum2 x y n = if ((x+y)==n && x>0 && y>0) then [x,y]:sum2 (x+1) (y-1) n else []
sum3 [] = []
sum3 (x:xs) = sum4 x 1 : sum3 xs
sum4 [] t = []
sum4 (x:xs) t = if not (x == t) then (sum1 x) else x
```

And yes, this was an excesice of an exam but i don't know how to doit

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? If you need help figuring out where to start, what patterns have you noticed? Maybe you can start with something simple, like what is `sum1 1`? Can you write `sum1 2` in terms of `sum1 1` and `2`?

Comment: i have been trying a lot. This excesice was from an exam i have just edit the question with my code. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that this is homework (and a harder one IMO) so I will not spoil everything right now.

If you think about it you should see that there are basically two operations of how you can get from a list `xs` that sums to `n` to a list that sums to `n+1`:

- you can add another `1`
- you can add `1` to some `x` in `xs`

so if you manage to implement both operations your task will be a lot easier.

The first one is not hard (*hint* `(1:)` is a function prepending an additional `1` to some list - now you have to *map* this...)

The second one is a bit harder although almost the same idea of divide&conquer will help you out.

Here is how I would start with it:

```
add1Somewhere :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
add1Somewhere [i] = [[i+1]]
add1Somewhere (i:is) = ???
```

(yes this is a *partial* function)

---

### remarks:

- as you can see below you don't really have to insert the additional `1` somewhere or choose any `x` in `xs` - using the first `x` in `xs` and prepending to the first place **does suffice**
- the algorithm I'm hinting at will produce sometimes equal outcomes - for example if you have one `[1,1]` then you can end up at `[2,2]` later in two ways: `[1,1] -> [2,1] -> [2,2]` and `[1,1] -> [1,2] -> [2,2]` - those can be removed with `Data.List.nub` or if you change your algorithm to produce ordered/filtered results (don't produce `[1,1] -> [1,2]`)
- your example is missing things `[1,1,1,1]` and I honestly could not tell if the exercise hints at one such order
- you probably should have a look at `concatMap` (or `concat`)
- this is different from the algorithm @cirdec is hinting at (probably his is faster) - but the same problems with duplication applies if you *insert an additional 1 at some place*

---

#### solution

as it's some time and you said it's an old exam question I think it's ok to spoil it (don't read on if you don't want to)

So this is a possible solution (no care taken on any performance issue):

```
import Data.List (nub)

sum1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [[a]]
sum1 1 = [[1]]
sum1 n = nub $ concatMap add1Somewhere ns ++ map (1:) ns
  where ns = sum1 (n-1)

add1Somewhere :: Num a => [a] -> [[a]]
add1Somewhere [i] = [[i+1]]
add1Somewhere (i:is) = ((i+1):is) : map (i:) (add1Somewhere is)
```

please note that this uses `concatMap` and `nub` both of which might or might not be ok for this.

I hope you get the basic idea

---

### obviously better solution

oops - I just noticed that you can get rid of all the *problematic* functions like `concat` and `nub` anyway as it's sufficient to just prepend a `1` or increment the very first list element - the recursion will provide all the needed permuations anyway (the different paths I mentioned are exactly the permutations) - *there is a difference in the order though*:

```
sum1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> [[a]]
sum1 1 = [[1]]
sum1 n = map add1 ns ++ map prep1 ns
  where ns          = sum1 (n-1)
        prep1 is    = 1:is
        add1 (i:is) = (i+1):is
```

of course you can replace the `map` with a list-comprehension if you want

#### proof that this finds all permutations

by Induction on `n` (assuming only positive natural numbers)

for `n=1` just notice that `[1]` is the only possible list

now assume that we find all permuations for `n>0` and look at some list `xs`
that will sum up to `n+1` (obviously the list needs to be non-empty)

Now the first element `x` of `xs = x:ys` will be either `1` or `>1`

- `x=1` - in this case `prep1` will provide `xs` because `ys` was found by our algorithm by induction (note that `sum ys = sum xs - 1 = n`)
- `x>1` - in this case `(x-1):ys` was found by our algorithm by induction and `add1` will create `xs` (again because `sum ((x-1):ys) = sum xs - 1 = n`)